# Please explain how works java method isChecked in RadioButton

Tags: java, android

I am new in programming. I am sorry for question. I can not understand what does it mean. Piese of code

```
  public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {    
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton)view).isChecked();
```

What does this sintaxis of construction mean, how is named it to find and read.((RadioButton)view)
Thank you.

Comment: It's casting the view to `RadioButton` so it can access a `RadioButton` method.

Comment: This is Type-Casting i.e, We get a `View` on `onRadioButtonClicked` method as a parameter. We can't use the functions associated with `RadioButton` on `View` object. So, we _Type-Cast_ `View` to `RadioButton`. In simple terms, we are saying the IDE to consider `view` as a `RadioButton`. Hope this makes sense. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View class inherits from RadioButton class.
This method - onRadioButtonClicked must for various reasons,accept an object of View kind.
but for use there parent's method - .isChecked() method You have to look at him in the 'glasses' of parent class.

its use polymorephism ability.
you can see more [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm#:%7E:text=Polymorphism%20is%20the%20ability%20of,is%20considered%20to%20be%20polymorphic.)